# Forming finite sumsets

Tags: list-manipulation

If $ A $ and $ B $ are finite sets, $ A+B $ is the set of all sums of an element of $ A $ with an element of $ B $.

For example, $ \{2,3,5\} + \{3,5,9\} = \{5,6,7,8,10,11,12,14\} $.

How can I program this in Mathematica?

Comment: `Sort@Union@(Total /@ Flatten[#, 1] &@
    Outer[List, {2, 3, 5}, {3, 5, 9}])` ?

Comment: @Syed Simpler to use `Plus` instead of `List` in the `Outer`. Also `Union` will sort it already. Saves a few key strokes...

Comment: As suggested by @DanielLichtblau :  `Union@Flatten[Outer[Plus, {2, 3, 5}, {3, 5, 9}]]`. Many thanks for the improvement.